# How to create an order to operate a Toggle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a checklist and it must to follow an chronological order.

In others words,

The checklist must be able to click one step a time. All checklist is disabled (interactalbe:false in Unity Inferface), and only the first element is active (interactable: on, Unity Interface too). When I click on the first Toggle, it's disabled and the next element is activated (interactable: false), like this:

**Start:**
-> Step 1 (active)
-> Step 2 (desactive)
-> Step 3 (desactive)

**Step 1 is clicked (checked)...**

-> Step 1 (desactive)
-> Step 2 (active)
-> Step 3 (desactive)

**Step 2 is clicked (checked)...**

-> Step 1 (desactive)
-> Step 2 (deactive)
-> Step 3 (active)

and so on...

I found functions like GetComponentInChildren, GetComponentInParent, GetComponents, GetComponentsInChildren, GetComponentsInParent. I tried insert in my code but without succesfull.

I think in two ways for made it:

1 - If the toggle is clicked... "get the next element-> active element"

2 - Create an array to get id of all toggles in my Element and: If the toggle is cliked... Get the ID of it and +1 in ID.

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine; 
using System.Collections; 
using UnityEngine.UI; 
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class AtivaBotao : MonoBehaviour {
    public Toggle checklist_toggle;

    public void Start(){
        checklist_toggle = this.GetComponent<Toggle>();
    }

    public void EnableDisable(Toggle checklist_toggle){
        if (checklist_toggle.interactable){
            checklist_toggle.interactable = false;
        }               
    } 
}
```

Actually, it active and desactive the toggle when it's clicked. How I said, I tried insert diferent functions but whitout succesfull.

In the end, what is the best method? And how I can update my code to make it?

Comment: Add property in each checkbox , NeighborID, something like that which is the ID of the next button. So when a checkbox is clicked, access the NeighborID and activate that neighbor checkbox and disable the current one

Comment: You only want just one toggle to be selected at a time?

Comment: @DanHunex Yes. Exatcly it I thinked, but I'm with trouble to transform it in code

Comment: @Programmer Yes! One at a time and in order. 1, 2, 3, 4... Like in the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a script and attach it to the parent of all your toggles :

```
private UnityEngine.UI.Toggle[] toggles;

void Start()
{
    toggles = GetComponentsInChildren<UnityEngine.UI.Toggle>();

    if( toggles.Length > 0 )
    {
        for( int i = 0 ; i < toggles.Length ; ++i )
        {
            int closureIndex = i ;
            toggles[closureIndex].interactable = false ;
            toggles[closureIndex].onValueChanged.addListener( (isOn) =>
               if( isOn )
               {
                    toggles[closureIndex].interactable = false;
                    if( closureIndex < toggles.Length - 1 )
                        toggles[closureIndex + 1].interactable = true ;
               }
            ) ;
        }
        toggles[0].interactable = true ;
    }
    else
         Debug.LogError("No toggle component in children!", this ) ;
}
```

Comment: I think this is what OP is looking for

Comment: Solved! That's exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks a lot!